# conditional defines for desktop and mobile compiler

Tags: delphi

I am working on a cross platform library that should compile in both desktop and mobile compilers supported by Delphi.
as we know strings in desktop is 1-based and mobile is 0-based.
is there any defines in Delphi that I can use to separate code that will compile in desktop and mobile and is backwards compatible at least down to XE2.

something more like if defines desktop do this else if mobile do this.

sorry for bad formatting. typing from Mobile.

Delphi version XE7 up 1.

Comment: The defines are well documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)

Comment: 0-based string indexing can be turned off using [`{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi))

Comment: @David, thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately in the platform section, I can't figure if  POSIX and posix32 belongs to desktop or mobile.
I will appreciate it if I can get any help in sorting the platform section to desktop and mobile.

Comment: @Remy, thanks but I would love to attempt other options first.

Comment: @Xor-el: All RTL functions are 1-based even in mobile. All String helper methods are 0-based even in desktop. The whole ZBS issue **only** affects the `[]` string index operator, nothing else. So you can write 1-based code in mobile, and 0-based code in desktop, if you want to. Embarcadero prefers everyone move away from the 1-based RTL and [use 0-based strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_iOS_from_Desktop#Use_0-Based_Strings) for everything, desktop and mobile alike. But if backward compatibility is an issue, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: @Remy it's a little more involved than that. It's no fun using one based Pos with zero based [], or vice versa with the string helper analogue. So you just need to decide whether to use rtl or string helper, and set the directive to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditionals are documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)

I think that the answer to the question that you asked is that you should switch on the `NEXTGEN` conditional.

However, just because you are compiling for mobile (i.e. `NEXTGEN`) does not mean that strings must zero based. Likewise there is no compulsion for desktop code to be one based. Zero based strings can be enabled/disabled with the [$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)) directive.

You really ought to try to avoid conditional compilation. Conditional compilation adds significant complexity, makes testing harder, and increases the risk off defects. I strongly recommend you try to avoid conditional compilation where possible.

So for each unit you should decide whether you are zero or one based and include the appropriate directive at the top of that unit. If you plan to use the one based RTL functions like `Pos` and `Copy`, be one based. Otherwise use the string helper (introduced in XE3) and be zero based. The decision isn't really related to whether or not your code targets desktop or mobile.

Finally, you say you want to support mobile on XE2, but the compiler there is FreePascal which uses one based strings. Supporting XE2 mobile is another layer of complexity.

Comment: XE2 does not support mobile development, only Windows and OSX.  iOS was added in XE4, and Android in XE6.

Comment: @Remy XE2 had iOS support via FPC. XE3 removed it. XE4 restored it via llvm based next gen compilers. You know this but have perhaps forgotten about the XE2 aberration.

Comment: @ David and Remy, thanks a lot for your splendid answers. I learnt a lot. I have decided to go with  RTL functions that are one based.

Comment: So you'll use `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}` in all of your units?

Comment: @ david , just edited my previous comment. typo error.
i will use {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS
OFF} in all my units.